# Se puede enviar state por props entre componentes sin renderizarlos? React

Tags: reactjs

Tengo dos componentes en react, uno es el perfil de usuario y otro es la pagina de mensajes

La cuestion es que en la pagina del perfil tengo un boton para enviar mensaje, al presionar ese boton me envia a la pagina mensajes, el tema que mensajes tiene su componente y el perfil otro lo que busco es enviar los datos del usuario con un state, ejemplo dentro del componente perfil

```
export default Perfil(){   
      return(
     <div>
 //Codigo..
    <Mensajes user={user}/>
 //Codigo..
    </div>
     )
}
```

Pero si hago eso me renderiza todo la pagina de mensajes dentro de la pagina perfil, cosa que no quiero

solo necesito pasar el "user" al componente Mensajes pero no encuentro la forma

Una solucion es por medio de la url, pero que pasaria si fuera un array de json?
hay alguna manera?

Answer (score 0):

prueba solo usando como funcion tu Componente

```
return(
     <div>
        {Mensajes user={user}} 
    </div>
     )
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no funciona, ojala haya una manera de usar a un componente como funcion

Comment: @MartinCarp en mi proyecto si funciona, que error te sale?

Comment: '}' expected.ts(1005)

Comment: me sale eso, uso hooks, no se si tendra algo que ver